# How to filter product cards by category?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am curious how can I filter content on the page by category, in such a way so when I click on, let`s say, "Philosophy" category, on the page will remain only books that are from that specific category, while other will be hidden. I am using Angular, Typescript and Angular-CLI for this project. Please explain me, as I want to understand this in depth.

Here is the source code of this example app: https://github.com/EgomortIncognitus/bookstore.

Comment: a filtering pipe? you can read about them in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to Angular [Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes). In order to create a "filterBy" pipe, you'll need to implement `PipeTransform` [interface](https://no-shadow-angular-io.firebaseapp.com/docs/ts/latest/api/core/PipeTransform-interface.html), which will as you can guess, transform any array dynamically.

Let's say you have an array looking like this :

```
const foo = [{
    title: 'bar',
    id: 2,
    color: 'red'
}
…]
```

And you want to filter it by one of it's objects fields... You should end up having something looking like this :

```
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filterBy'
})

@Injectable()
export class FilterByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform( array: Array<any>, filterField: string, filterValue: string ): Array<any> {
        if (!array) return [];
        return array.filter(item => item[filterField] == filterValue);
    }
}
```

Use in HTML, to only obtain 'red' objects :

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of array | filterBy: 'color' : 'red'">
```

Comment: Got it, in some way... But this snippet for html I should include in every single button for every single category, am I right?

Comment: Not sure I got your question right. You can use the filterBy pipe in any *ngFor structure, and can use variables and models to add more filter categories. For instance :

<input #myInput placeholder="first name" />
<div *ngFor="let item of array | filterBy: 'color' : myInput.value"></div>

Comment: Here is what I tried but not working, although I know that I mistake somewhere ignorantly. Please guide me a bit.

'import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterCategory'
})

@Injectable()
export class FilterCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(books: Array<any>, filterField: string, filterValue: string): Array<any> {
    if (!books) return [];
    return books.filter(category => category[filterField] === filterValue);
  }

}'

Comment: FYI ... you should not use pipes for filtering unless you are certain that your list will be small and you are not worried about performance. See the info here: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 0):

I have a complete example of this here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-CLI-Final

Here is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { IProduct } from './product';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

    _listFilter: string;
    get listFilter(): string {
        return this._listFilter;
    }
    set listFilter(value: string) {
        this._listFilter = value;
        this.filteredProducts = this.listFilter ? this.performFilter(this.listFilter) : this.products;
    }

    filteredProducts: IProduct[];
    products: IProduct[] = [];

    performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
        filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
              product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
    }

}
```

Then you just bind to the filteredProducts variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Pipes for the same . For eg

In this case we are typing the value to filter but you can bind it to a button which will pass value to the pipe

html template

```
<label class="control">Filter items
    <input class="edit-Label" type=”text” [(ngModel)]='filter' placeholder="Filter"
               onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Filter'"/>
</label>

*ngFor="let i of comments | myFilter: filter // is comming from the input here you can make use of button to pass value to filter
```

Pipe component

```
@Pipe({
      name: 'myFilter'
    })

    export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform{

      transform(value: any[], q: string) {
        if (!q || q === '') {
          return value;
        }
        return value.filter(item => -1 < item.comment.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()));
      }
    }
```